# Java not starting for some users via Citrix

Tags: java, citrix

I have an issue with Java not starting for some users on our Citrix server.

The settings are the same for all users on the Domain/ADs, but some users receive "The page you are viewing uses Java. More information on Java support is available from the Micosoft Website."

On a user it doesn't work for, I can see that Java is there and Enabled in IE when I check the addons.

All users have write access to the cache as well.
On Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1.

I have tried googling this but I've come up short.

Would be very thankful in any assistance regarding this issue.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the version of IE they're using?   Recent versions of Firefox & Chrome refuse to run the java plugin.  This is for safety reasons.  For the same reasons they still support Flash.  Ahaaa!!

Comment: All users run the same IE, and the problems occurs on the same page(s) as well.

Comment: It used to be the case that when a user on Citrix started IE, the IE ran locally, ie. on the users PC.  Is that still the case?

Comment: No, the IE is running on the Citrix. I've also RDPd and opened IE with users that work / don't work and it still behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

Works after deleting and then recreating the Active Directory user.
Also moved the "C:\user\username-with-java-issues\" to another location and cleared user in regedit after the deletion.